# How can I create a file with a variable name in pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid

```
@view_config(route_name='home_page', renderer='templates/edit.pt')
def home_page(request):
    if 'form.submitted' in request.params:
        name= request.params['name'] 
        body = request.params['body'] 
        renderer_dict = dict(name=name,body=body) 
        new_comment = render('new_page.pt', renderer_dict, request=request) 
        with open('tutorial:templates/{name}.html','w') as file:
            file.write(new_comment)  
        return HTTPFound(location=request.static_url('tutorial:pages/{pagename}.html',pagename=name)) 

    return {}
```

Right now this is a view callable I have in my pyramid app that is for my apps home page. I am concerned about the line where file is created (with open...). I want the name of the file to be the same name defined by the request.params in the code above but I am not sure how to pass the variable (I doubt brackets are the right solution). I then want .html to be added to that name to make it a full file name. I am not sure what syntax to use in order to do this

Edit: I also would like advice on how to correctly do this on the return HTTPFound line. I would like it to redirect to that new file. Right now I have {pagename}.html but doubt that this is sufficient. I feel like the solution to this is the same as to the with open line but please correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: This sounds to me like the sort of use case that would be well served by traversal. (It's certainly possible to do it with routes if you want to do it that way, though.)

Comment: the `tutorial:some/file.html` is syntax specific to pyramid's template renderer as far as I know. It's not applicable elsewhere.

Comment: by that syntax do you mean the asset specification? Do you think it is inappropriate t use it for the request.static_url? I was going off this: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.static_url which seems to advocate the use of such asset specifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first off, i think you probably should NOT be doing whatever it is that you're trying to do.

second, to open the file...

```
    name = request.params['name'] 
    app_dir = SEE_BELOW
    filename =  "%(app_dir)s/templates/%(name)s" % { 'app_dir':app_dir , 'name':name }
    filename =  "%s/templates/%s" % ( app_dir , name )
    with open(filename,'w') as file:
        file.write(new_comment)
```

i'm going to note a few things:

1. app_dir - i forget how to get the actual pyramid app dir.  i usually get spooked by this stuff, so only use specific subdirectories like such:

env.ini
    templates_writable_dir = %(here)s/app/templates/writable/

then i can access it via:
    request.registry.settings['templates_writable_dir']

note that i made a specific writable subfolder.  i don't want the main stuff writable.  i'll chmod/grp that writable folder so the user pyramid runs as can ed it.  i won't allow that user to write to anything else.

1. `"tutorial:templates/{name}.html"` that is using the templated syntax, which only works in the templates. one of your pyramid plugins injects the `renderer_dict` into the template and renders it for you.  you need to use normal python string formatting, as i showed above using two options.

More importantly...

based on your question, you're not just new to pyramid but to python too.  i'd suggest doing a few quick python tutorials before jumping into Pyramid - or any other framework.

Comment: I appreciate your candidness. Can you elaborate on why I should NOT be doing what I am trying to do? Is it because I should learn more about python before writing pyramid apps or is it because there is something fundamentally unsound about what I am trying to do (security holes, ect.)

Comment: additionally: is there a reason you are putting it in templates? My intention is to use a file in templates to create an html string (.html file) that goes in a different directory (app_dir/pages/___.html)

Comment: Largely for security holes and (possibly) performance issues. A written file can accidentally overwrite real code, or one template file re-writes another. If you do something like this, you really need to build in a file management system ). Depending on the template system you use, the files can run arbitrary python code.

And taking another look at your code- you'd ideally write this into a "/static" directory (not "/templates") since this is a rendered page.

Why not futureproof your design and save the data into a store, and then render the html using the most recent template available ?

Comment: "is there a reason you are putting it in templates?"  Answer: you were opening a file with write permissions under 'templates'

Comment: my mistake with the templates vs pages directories. Aside from that, would putting my data into a store and then rendering it with a template be slower than just calling the html file from the filesystem? speed is very important to me, and eventually I want the data to contain around 1MB of information (so too big for a database). Also would putting the data into a store reduce security holes? Finally, I realize the issue of rewriting files by uploading a new file with the same name. I hope to take care of this eventually by replacing the filenames with (randomstring).html

Comment: Reading off filesystem is faster, especially because you can just bypass Pyramid entirely.  Most people front webapps with a server like nginx that will serve static directories themselves.  If you put the data into a database, you don't have to worry about filesystem permissions - you are your own biggest security risk on stuff like that.  If you can serve everything from this function out of a specific dedicated directory, like "/static/generated_files/", you can avoid most issues.

Comment: the big thing you need to do, is make sure that you keep your app with the ability to write/edit files within that single subdirectory.  you're likely to be your own worst enemy.  i've seen team members wipe out large sections of a dev environment because the code was sloppy and they ran something as root to bypass filesystem permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that standard open understand tutorial:templtes and even {name}

use request.static_path there before use open

Comment: standard "open" function in python do nothing about any template language, so
`with open('tutorial:templates/{name}.html','w') as file:`
change to
`with open( request.static_path('tutorial:templates/{name}.html'),'w') as file:`
or use there any function which understand `tutorial:templates/{name}.html` and can replace it to path